# Generating function of $a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\frac{1}{k})+\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics

Let $$a_n=\sum_{k=1}^{n}(\frac{1}{k})+\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}$$

I want to determine the generating function of $a_n$.

I could show that $$\binom{2n}{n}=(-4)^n(-1)^n\frac{1/2(1/2+1)(1/2+2)\dots(1/2+n-1)}{n!}=(-4)^n\binom{-1/2}{n}$$
using
[image]
And we have that $$\sum_{n\geq0}\binom{-1/2}{n}(-4)^nz^n=(1-4z)^{-1/2}$$

> But I don't know how to arrive at (i.e. what to do with the factor $\frac{1}{n+1}$) $$\frac{1}{n+1}\binom{2n}{n}=\frac{1-(1-4z)^{1/2}}{2z}$$

The generating function of $$\sum_{k=1}^{n}\frac{1}{k}$$ should be $$\frac{z}{1-z}\cdot \underbrace{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{n}}_{={-\log(1-z)}}$$

or is this wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/904248), the generating function of the [Harmonic Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Harmonic_number) is
$$
\sum_{n=1}^\infty H_nx^n
=-\frac{\log(1-x)}{1-x}\tag{1}
$$
and as shown in [this answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/355723), the generating function of the [Catalan Numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Catalan_number) is
$$
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac1{k+1}\binom{2k}{k}x^k
=\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}\tag{2}
$$
Your sequence seems to be the sum of these sequences, so its generating function would be
$$
-\frac{\log(1-x)}{1-x}+\frac{1-\sqrt{1-4x}}{2x}\tag3
$$